# Localize DatePicker

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to localize `DatePicker`. From what I read the dialog uses system locale instead of current thread locale. Is there a workaround?

As of now, my application supports three languages user can choose from (ResourceManagers in the .NETStandard project). If the device uses different language, the whole application will be in English except for `DatePicker` which will be in the system language.

Both of the following are acceptable solutions:

- User can choose which language they wish to use throughout the lifetime of the application
- Application uses the system language if it's supported, English otherwise

**Edit:**

Custom renderer implementation as suggested by Raimo

```
public class LocaleAwareDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer{
  public LocaleAwareDatePickerRenderer( Context context ) : base(context) { }
  protected override EditText CreateNativeControl() {
    return new EditText(Context) {TextLocale = new Locale("cs"), Focusable = false, Clickable = true, Tag = this};
  }
}
```

Comment: You want the Text of time to be in different language format or the popped up date dialog in different language?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom [`DatePickerRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/DatePickerRenderer.cs) and add these two lines to set your control's Locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(LocalizationService.GetCurrentThreadCultureInfo().TwoLetterISOLanguageName);
Control.TextLocale = locale;
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide the full renderer implementation? As `TextLocale` doesn't seem to be an accessible property

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding the project uncovered the property, verifying now

Comment: I did as you instructed, but the `DatePicker` remains in system language